# Extension 'cogs.__pycach' could not be loaded. discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to set up my python bot to work with my extensions that are in the folder "cogs". However, the following error happens while launching it

> discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionNotFound: Extension 'cogs.__pycach' could not be loaded.

I'm using the following code to load and unload my extensions:

```
async def load(ctx, extension):
    bot.load_extension(f'commands.{extension}')

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```

This problem is however fixed if I delete the pycache folder, but the folder has to be deleted every time the bot restarts.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not include "thanks", or even worse "Thanks in advanceD" in your questions. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it and here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is trying to load everything that's in this directory, so in this example the code try to load `_pycache_` which I think is not a cog :P.
You could try this one:

```
extensions = [
    '[modulename]',
    ]
```

e.g.

```
extensions = [
    'data.testCog'
    ]
```

This "." (dot) is used to mark the directory (if `testCog.py` file is in data folder). Then you can make an if and for loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for extension in extensions:
        bot.load_extension(extension)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method. Load only python files.

```
for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
```